# Print multiple scrolling lines in parallel using python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Trying to print multiple scrolling lines on terminal using python. The following is the code:

```
import os, sys, time
import threading

def scroll_text(content, line, scroll_limit, sleep_time):
    blank_line = "\r" + " " * scroll_limit
    buf = ""

    if line > 0:
        sys.stdout.write("\r\n" * line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    for cindex in range(0, len(content), 1):
        sys.stdout.write(blank_line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        buf = content[cindex:cindex + scroll_limit]
        for itr in range(0, len(buf), 1):
            if buf[itr] == "\n":
                buf[itr] = "-"
        buf = "".join(buf)
        if buf != "":
            sys.stdout.write("\r" + buf)
            sys.stdout.flush()

        time.sleep(sleep_time)

fd = open('chat.txt', 'r')
content = fd.read()

content_list = list(content)

fd.close()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=scroll_text, args=(content_list, 0, 70, 0.05))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=scroll_text, args=(content_list, 1, 70, 0.05))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Noticed that only the second thread is called, and the text is scrolling on the second line. Not sure whether I am doing something wrong here. I am a newbie so please forgive my coding mistakes

Added:

The following is the curses version:

```
import os, sys, time
import threading
import curses

def report(line_no, text):
        stdscr.addstr(line_no, 0, text)
        stdscr.refresh()

def scroll_text(content, line, scroll_limit, sleep_time):
    itr1 = 0
    for itr in range(0, len(content) - 1, 1):
        if content[itr] == "\n" or content[itr] == "\r\n":
            content[itr] = '-'

    report(line, "\r" + " " * scroll_limit + "\r")
    for itr in range(0, len(content), 1):
        buf = "".join(content[itr:itr + scroll_limit])

        buf = buf.rstrip()

        if buf != "":
            report(line, "\r" + buf)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)

fd = open('chat.txt', 'r')
content = list(fd.read())
fd.close()

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()

try:
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=scroll_text, args=(content, 0, 70, 0.05))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=scroll_text, args=(content, 1, 70, 0.05))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

except:
    curses.echo()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.endwin()
finally:
    curses.echo()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.endwin()
```

Here is the [video](http://hidemyass.com/files/fsyxv/) of the output with curses version

Comment: Why did you `import curses`?

Comment: Hi Jan, sorry that line remained after a failed attempt to use curses to print instead of sys.stdout.write() :) removing the line

Comment: The curses version is actually working in single CPU machine :)

Answer (score 0):

A few simple remarks:

- I don't see why you duplicate `content_list` as `content1` and `content2` to later pass `content1` twice as argument. Maybe your second thread should use `content2` and not `content1`:

  ```
  thread2 = threading.Thread(target=scroll_text, args=(content2, 1, 70, 0.05))
  ```
- You should close your filehandles at the end, for example:

  ```
  fd.close()
  ```
- You probably use `sys.stdout.write()` on purpose, I would just like to mention the following way to print to STDOUT:

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function   # python3 compatible, changes the syntax a little bit

  print (something)   # newline is inclusive, you don't need to add '+ \n'
  ```

Comment: Thanks adbar, made changes suggested by you. The second thread seems to execute, but not the first one

Comment: The following is the curses version: